# Как прижать fixed блок к правому краю?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Блок `nav-right`, который находится сейчас слева, должен быть прижат к правому краю. Мне нужно что бы у него остался `position: fixed`, но когда я с ним пытаюсь переместить этот блок к правому краю, то ничего не происходит. Но при этом, когда я убираю `position: fixed;`, я не могу выставить `height: 100%;`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #F0F1F4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D1D4E4;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

input {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #323546;
  background-color: #D1D4E4;
  opacity: .7;
}

input:hover {
  opacity: .8;
  transition: .3s;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: 1;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #323546;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: #323546;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.header-nav {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.search {
  width: 141px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background-image: url(../icons/search.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left 5px;
}


/* Side Bar */

.nav-right {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #323546;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #323546;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #41455C;
}

.nav-item-setting {
  background-image: url(../icons/cog.svg);
}

.nav-item-calendar {
  background-image: url(../icons/calendar.svg);
}

.nav-item-bell {
  background-image: url(../icons/bell.svg);
}

.nav-item-trash {
  background-image: url(../icons/trash.svg);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="AirCargoSoft" width="142px" height="18px"></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="header-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Заказы</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контрагенты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Поставщики</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Справочники</a></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="search" class="search" placeholder="Поиск">
</header>
<nav class="nav-right">
  <div class="nav-items">
    <a href="#"><button class="nav-item-setting nav-item"></button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="nav-item-calendar nav-item"></button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="nav-item-bell nav-item"></button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="nav-item-trash nav-item"></button></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить `right: 0px;` для `.nav-right`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #F0F1F4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D1D4E4;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

input {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #323546;
  background-color: #D1D4E4;
  opacity: .7;
}

input:hover {
  opacity: .8;
  transition: .3s;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: 1;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #323546;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: #323546;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.header-nav {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.search {
  width: 141px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background-image: url(../icons/search.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left 5px;
}


/* Side Bar */

.nav-right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #323546;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #323546;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #41455C;
}

.nav-item-setting {
  background-image: url(../icons/cog.svg);
}

.nav-item-calendar {
  background-image: url(../icons/calendar.svg);
}

.nav-item-bell {
  background-image: url(../icons/bell.svg);
}

.nav-item-trash {
  background-image: url(../icons/trash.svg);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="AirCargoSoft" width="142px" height="18px"></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="header-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Заказы</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контрагенты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Поставщики</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Справочники</a></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="search" class="search" placeholder="Поиск">
</header>
<nav class="nav-right">
  <div class="nav-items">
    <a href="#"><button class="nav-item-setting nav-item"></button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="nav-item-calendar nav-item"></button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="nav-item-bell nav-item"></button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="nav-item-trash nav-item"></button></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```